# How to use Composite Keys for Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
define([
'backbone'
], function(Backbone) {
var Model = BaseModel.extend({
    urlRoot:"/api/v1/processinggroups/version/step/param",
    idAttribute: 'extParamId',

    initialize: function(model, options) {
        var defaults;
        if (typeof model === "undefined") {
            defaults = {
                "businessId": null,
                "extParamId": null,
                "pgStepName": null,
                "extProcName": null,
                "extParamName": null,
            };
        }
        this.set(defaults);
    },
});
return ProcessGrpExternalParamsModel;
```

});

This is the model i am currently using.
But I Want idAttribute to be combination of two values like

idAttribute: 'extParamId' and "businessId"

or

idAttribute: extParamId + "-" + businessId

Is it possible to achieve this.
How do we achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set it within `constructor`

```
var Model = BaseModel.extend({
  constructor: function(model) {
    this.idAttribute = model.extParamId + '-' + model.businessId;
  }
});
```